# "1 Answer" in various colors

Tags: feature-request, design

Currently, the site works where the number of answers is displayed under the question (I'm in Unanswered view). If the asker chooses an answer as correct, then the color goes from light green to dark green, and it disappears a short time later.

Is it possible to have it work like this:

- Question w/o answer: grey, (0 Answers, no answers, or unanswered)
- Question w/ non-upvoted answers: grey, "2 Answers"
- Question with upvoted answer: light green, "1 Answer"
- Question with "correct" answer: dark green, "2 Answers"

This is just a small small detail, but would be convenient to see if someone already has an upvoted answer posted.

Answer (score 1):

> [W]ould be convenient to see if someone already has an upvoted answer
>   posted.

The [Unanswered](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) tab lists "questions with no upvoted answers" (description at upper right-hand side of page) - upvoting an answer effectively removes the question from this tab.

Comment: Not if you don't refresh the page. (and let the jQuery? show you the status change of a question.)